# Wordpress 3 steps ajax filter search with select option

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, search

I want to create a custom post type search with 3 steps of select box
the select boxes are:

1. parent taxonomies that used for provinces (parent taxonomy)
2. child taxonomies that used for towns (child taxonomy)
3. posts that created for each billboard (posts)

in each post admin must checked at least town of that billboard in

now I have one search box that must show billboards if user search province,town or billboard

and three html select box that must works like this:

first user select one of the province, in second select box must show the town that is in selected province and in the third select box must show the billboards related to selected town and province

also maybe user wants to just select province: in this case search result should be all billboards related to that province.
or maybe user just wants to click town select or just wants to search in all billboards. any way it should works fine! ;)

till now I create ajax search that just works with each select box separately. I mean If I select province in first select box I see all towns inside and outside the province in second select box and this happens to billboards too:

This is my code so far - the PHP:

```
<?php
function en_ads_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('en_ads_css', get_theme_file_uri() . '/assets/css/en-ads.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('en_ads_ajax_filter_search', get_theme_file_uri() . '/assets/js/en-ads.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    wp_localize_script('en_ads_ajax_filter_search', 'ajax_url', admin_url('admin-ajax.php')); //en_ads_ajax_filter_search must be like en-ads.js and used in it
}

// Shortcode: [en_ads_shortcode]
add_shortcode('en_ads_shortcode', 'en_ads_search_structure');
function en_ads_search_structure()
{
    en_ads_scripts();

    ob_start(); ?>
    <div id="post-ajax-filter-search">
        <form action="" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="search" id="ajax-input-search" placeholder="نام مکان تابلو را وارد کنید">
            <div class="search-option__list">
                <?php
                $searchFieldsQuery = get_posts(array(
                    'post_type' => 'en-ads',
                    'post_status' => array('publish', 'future'),
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'hierarchical' => true
                ));
                if ($searchFieldsQuery) { ?>
                    <div class="search-option__item">
                        <label for="enProvince" class="search-option__item--label">استان</label>
                        <select name="enProvince" id="enProvince" class="search-option__item--select">
                            <option value="">همه استان‌ها</option>
                            <?php $term_query = new WP_Term_Query(array('taxonomy' => 'en-ads-cat', 'parent' => 0));
                            if (!empty($term_query->terms)) {
                                foreach ($term_query->terms as $term) {
                                    echo '<option value="' . $term->name . '">' . $term->name . '</option>';
                                }
                            } ?>
                            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="search-option__item">
                        <label for="enTown" class="search-option__item--label">شهر</label>
                        <select name="enTown" id="enTown" class="search-option__item--select">
                            <option value="">همه شهرها</option>
                            <?php $term_query = new WP_Term_Query(array('taxonomy' => 'en-ads-cat', 'parent' => 0));
                            if (!empty($term_query->terms)) {
                                foreach ($term_query->terms as $term) {
                                    $term_children = get_term_children($term->term_id, 'en-ads-cat');
                                    foreach ($term_children as $children) {
                                        $child = get_term_by('id', $children, 'en-ads-cat');
                                        echo '<option value="' . $child->name . '">' . $child->name . '</option>';
                                    }
                                }
                            } ?>
                            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="search-option__item">
                        <label for="billboard" class="search-option__item--label">تابلو</label>
                        <select name="billboard" id="billboard" class="search-option__item--select">
                            <option value="">همه تابلو‌ها</option>
                            <?php foreach ($searchFieldsQuery as $sfq) { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $sfq->post_title; ?>"><?php echo $sfq->post_title; ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>

            <input type="submit" id="ajax-submit" name="submit" value="جستجو">
        </form>
        <div id="ajax_filter_search_results">
            <ul class="ajax_filter_search_results__list"></ul>
        </div>
        <button class="download-pdf">
            <span class="download-pdf--num">0</span>
            <img src="<?php echo esc_url(get_theme_file_uri()); ?>/assets/images/download_document_as_pdf.svg" alt="download billboard(s) as pdf" width="80px" height="auto">
        </button>
    </div>
<?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}

// Ajax Callback
add_action('wp_ajax_en_ads_ajax_filter_search', 'en_ads_ajax_filter_search_callback'); //wp_ajax_{js action}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_en_ads_ajax_filter_search', 'en_ads_ajax_filter_search_callback'); //wp_ajax_nopriv_{js action}

function en_ads_ajax_filter_search_callback(){
    header("Content-Type: application/json");

    $meta_query = array('relation' => 'AND');

    if (isset($_GET['enProvince'])) {
        $enProvince = sanitize_text_field($_GET['enProvince']);
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'en-ads-cat',
            'field' => 'name',
            'terms' => $enProvince
        );
    }
    if (isset($_GET['enTown'])) {
        $enTown = sanitize_text_field($_GET['enTown']);
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'en-ads-cat',
            'field' => 'name',
            'terms' => $enTown
        );
    }
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'en-ads',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        // 'meta_query' => $meta_query,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
            'taxonomy' => 'en-ads-cat',
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => array($enProvince,$enTown),
            'operator' => 'IN',
        ))
    );
    if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
        $search = sanitize_text_field($_GET['search']);
        $search_query = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'en-ads',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'meta_query' => $meta_query,
            's' => $search
        ));
    } else {
        $search_query = new WP_Query($args);
    }
    if ($search_query->have_posts()) {

        $result = array();

        while ($search_query->have_posts()) {
            $search_query->the_post();
            $result[] = array(
                "id" => get_the_ID(),
                "billboard" => get_the_title(),
                "permalink" => get_permalink(),
                "enProvince" => ,
                "enTown" => ,
                "enAdLight" => get_field('en_ads_light'),
                "enAdSize" => get_field('en_ads_billboard'),
                "enAdDate" => get_the_date('Y/m/d'),
                "enAdPrimaryPrice" => get_field('en_ads_primary_price'),
                "poster" => wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()), 'full')
            );
        }
        wp_reset_query();

        echo json_encode($result);
    } else {
        // no posts found
    }
    wp_die();
}
```

and the Jquery

```
$ = jQuery;

var pafs = $("#post-ajax-filter-search");
var pafsForm = pafs.find("form");

pafsForm.submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (pafsForm.find("#ajax-input-search").val().length !== 0) {
    var search = pafsForm.find("#ajax-input-search").val();
  }
  if (pafsForm.find("#billboard").val().length !== 0) {
    var search = pafsForm.find("#billboard").val();
  }
  if (pafsForm.find("#enProvince").val().length !== 0) {
    var enProvince = pafsForm.find("#enProvince").val();
    // console.log(enProvince);
  }
  if (pafsForm.find("#enTown").val().length !== 0) {
    var enTown = pafsForm.find("#enTown").val();
  }
  var inputData = {
    action: "en_ads_ajax_filter_search",
    search: search,
    enProvince: enProvince,
    enTown: enTown,
  };
  console.log(inputData);
  $.ajax({
    url: ajax_url,
    data: inputData,
    success: function (response) {
      pafs.find(".ajax_filter_search_results__list").empty();
      console.log(response);
      if (response) {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
          (response[i].enAdLight) ? enAdLightText = 'دارد' : enAdLightText = 'ندارد';
          var html = ` 
                    <li id="ad-${response[i].id}" class="ad-item ad-item--add-to-pdf">
                        <img src="${response[i].poster}" alt="${response[i].billboard}" class="ad-item__image--img">
                        <div class="ad-item__info">
                            <h4 class="ad-item__info--billboard">موقعیت تابلو: ${response[i].billboard}</h4>
                            <div class="ad-item__info--list">
                              <p class="ad-item__info--item">استان: ${response[i].enProvince}</p>
                              <p class="ad-item__info--item">شهر: ${response[i].enTown}</p>
                              <p class="ad-item__info--item">نور: ${enAdLightText}</p>
                              <p class="ad-item__info--item">اندازه: ${response[i].enAdSize}</p>
                              <p class="ad-item__info--item">زمان واگذاری: ${response[i].enAdDate}</p>
                              <p class="ad-item__info--item">قیمت اولیه: ${response[i].enAdPrimaryPrice} ریال</p>
                              <label class="ad-item__info--item ad-item__info--item-label">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="${response[i]}" class="ad-item__info--add-to-pdf" checked>
                              اضافه کردن به خروجی PDF</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ad-item__pdf-info">
                          <div class="ad-item__pdf-info-row">
                            <p class="ad-item__pdf-info--item">موقعیت تابلو: ${response[i].enProvince}-${response[i].enTown}-${response[i].billboard}</p>
                            <p class="ad-item__pdf-info--item">نور: ${enAdLightText}</p>
                            <p class="ad-item__pdf-info--item">اندازه: ${response[i].enAdSize}</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="ad-item__pdf-info-row">
                            <p class="ad-item__pdf-info--item">زمان واگذاری: ${response[i].enAdDate}</p>
                            <p class="ad-item__pdf-info--item">قیمت اولیه: ${response[i].enAdPrimaryPrice} ریال</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    `;
          pafs.find(".ajax_filter_search_results__list").append(html);
        }

        //add to pdf method
        $('.download-pdf--num').html($('.ad-item--add-to-pdf').length); //count pdf items each time search clicked
        $('.ad-item__info--add-to-pdf').click(function () {
          if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).closest('.ad-item').addClass("ad-item--add-to-pdf");
          } else {
            $(this).closest('.ad-item').removeClass("ad-item--add-to-pdf");
          }
          $('.download-pdf--num').html($('.ad-item--add-to-pdf').length); //count each time checkbox clicked
        });
        //Print mathod
        const downloadPdf = $('.download-pdf');
        downloadPdf.addClass("download-pdf--can-download");
        downloadPdf.click(function () {
          var WinPrint = window.print();
          WinPrint.focus();
          WinPrint.print();
          WinPrint.close();
        });
      }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
      pafs.find(".ajax_filter_search_results__list").empty();
      if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
        var errorText = "اتصال به شبکه را بررسی نمایید";
      } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
        var errorText = "صفحه مورد نظر پیدا نشد (خطای 404)";
      } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
        var errorText = "خطای سرور (خطای 500)";
      } else if (exception === "parsererror") {
        var errorText = "تابلو مورد نظر شما پیدا نشد";
      } else if (exception === "timeout") {
        var errorText = "Time out error";
      } else if (exception === "abort") {
        var errorText = "درخواست بی نتیجه";
      } else {
        var errorText = "خطای پیش بینی نشده";
      }
      var html = `
      <li class='no-result'>${errorText}</li>
      `;
      pafs.find(".ajax_filter_search_results__list").append(html);

      $('.download-pdf--num').html($('.ad-item--add-to-pdf').length); //count pdf items each time search clicked
      const downloadPdf = $('.download-pdf');
      downloadPdf.removeClass("download-pdf--can-download");
    },
  });
});

/* <a href="${response[i].permalink}" title="${response[i].billboard}" class="ad-item__info--more">
اطلاعات بیشتر
<i class="fas fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a> */

//add image to pdf first page and last page
var htmlBeforeResult = `
        <div class="pdf-first-page">
          <img src="${siteURLData.root_url}/wp-content/themes/hello-elementor-child/assets/images/pdf-first-page.jpg" class="pdf-first-page--img" width="100%" height="100%">
        </div>
        `;
var htmlAfterResult = `
        <div class="pdf-last-page">
          <img src="${siteURLData.root_url}/wp-content/themes/hello-elementor-child/assets/images/pdf-last-page.jpg" class="pdf-last-page--img" width="100%" height="100%">
        </div>  
        `
$("#ajax_filter_search_results").before(htmlBeforeResult);
$("#ajax_filter_search_results").after(htmlAfterResult);
```

I can't find related qustions on stack that I can implement on my code so any useful help is great!